# Remove face by Index - three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js, 3d, pythreejs

I got a **mesh** based on a geometry of different faces.

I'd like to remove a single face from this geometry during runtime.

**Is this possible using three.js?**

---

```
let mesh = new THREE.Mesh(
  geometry,
  textures
);
mesh.name = "map"
scene.add(mesh)

// runtime function should e.g. remove face with index 15
faceToDelete = {
  distance: 1000,
  face: Tb {a: 10756, b: 10758, c: 10757, normal: n, vertexNormals: 
  Array(3)},
  faceIndex: 15,
  object: ra {name: "map", type: "Mesh"},
  point: n {x: 87.01836565006928, y: 50, z: -245.99743779172834},
  uv: C {x: 0.3701836565006929, y: 0.9799871889586418},
} // (copied from console)

delete faceToDelete // does not seems to work without producing deep errors
```

---

Is there a method to achieve what I want?

Comment: Take a look at this [forum topic](https://discourse.threejs.org/t/how-to-remove-interior-faces-while-keeping-exterior-faces-untouched/4869/2?u=prisoner849)

Comment: Thanks for your reply but this is not really a matching solution.